# How to show number of asterisks to nearest thousand?

Tags: java, rounding

```
    bar1 = store1/1000;
    System.out.print("Store 1: ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= bar1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
```

How to show number of "*" rounded up or down to the nearest thousand. Right now it just rounds down.

Comment: Should it *always* round up?

Comment: only if its the number is above 500. Ex. (17580) should have 18 "*" (asterisks) and (22340) should have 22 asterisks

Comment: Assuming `bar` and `store1` are integers, then it is not rounding down now, nor is it rounding at all.

Comment: @squash69, the usual convention is that the middle value is also rounded up. Is it ok for you, or do you insist on "*above* 500"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
bar1 = (store1+500)/1000;
    System.out.print("Store 1: ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= bar1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    double store1 = 1095;
    long bar1 = Math.round(store1 / 1000);
    // int bar1 = store1/1000;
    System.out.print("Store 1: ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= bar1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
```

or if stre 1 is an int and you can't change it you can use:

```
    int store1 = 1095;
    long bar1 = Math.round(((double)store1) / 1000);
    // int bar1 = store1/1000;
```

It will round the value of store1/1000 to the nearest 1000.